# How to count how many nodes have input and output degree greater than 2 in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'd like to know how many nodes have input and output degree greater than 2 in Neo4j using Cypher.

Comment: Both the input and output degrees larger than 2, or their total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE size((n)-->()) > 2 AND size((n)<--()) > 2
RETURN count(n)
```

Comment: I wonder if `DISTINCT` is necessary - `MATCH (n)` already returns unique results.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[out]->()
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[in]-()
WITH n, COUNT(out) AS outDegree, COUNT(in) AS inDegree
WHERE outDegree > 2
  AND inDegree > 2
RETURN COUNT(n)
```

Comment: while this works (upvote for that), I found count to be unnecessary expensive and posted my solution using size()... also the OP is apparently only interested in the number of nodes, not the actually content.

Comment: Good point, I tend to forget about the fact that you can use patterns in `WHERE` along with `size`.